# How to loop through all remote branches and ignore HEAD

Tags: git

When I check my remote branches

```
git branch -r

  remotes/1
  remotes/2
  remotes/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/3
  remotes/4
  remotes/5
```

I want to checkout all the remote branches with one command. I can just loop through the output of `git branch -r` but than it's showing problems with the `HEAD --> origin/master` part which I want to ignore:

```
error: unknown switch `>'
usage: git checkout [<options>] <branch>
   or: git checkout [<options>] [<branch>] -- <file>...
```

Is there a way to ignore that part?

Comment: Try `git branch -r | grep -v "->"`

Comment: It must be `git branch -r | grep -v -- "->"`. Otherwise you get `grep: invalid option -- '>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Most stable will be to read the fields from the answer by awk:

```
git branch -r | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F/ '{print "remote="$1"; branch="$2";" }' | while read l
do eval $l
    echo git checkout -b $branch $remote/$branch
done
```

or something similar.

Comment: The second awk could be replaced with `sed 's@([^/]*)/(.*)@remote = \1; branch = \2@'` to handle branches that contains `/`.